# google plus api invalid_request

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-plus

I have been trying to fix this for the last couple of days. I have read all the forum and still no solution. Any help is appreciated.

I have been trying to use the refresh code. ( I dont want to reuse the access code as it expires). My code is based on http://www.jensbits.com/demos/ga/app/ga_app_oauth2_refreshtoken.txt.

code is as follows:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $accessToken = get_oauth2_token($_REQUEST['code'],"online"); //refresh_token not fetched
```

}

***//Note if I replace the above line with $client->authenticate() and then $client->getAccessToken(), the program is working. But then I am not getting refresh code***

Below I am pasting the function from the link

```
function get_oauth2_token3($grantCode, $grantType) {
$redirect_uri = "xxxx";

$oauth2token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$clienttoken_post = array(
    "client_id" => GCLIENT_ID,
    "client_secret" => GCLIENT_SECRET);

if ($grantType === "online") {
    $clienttoken_post["code"] = $grantCode;
    $clienttoken_post["redirect_uri"] = $redirect_uri;
    $clienttoken_post["grant_type"] = "authorization_code";
}

if ($grantType === "offline") {
    $clienttoken_post["refresh_token"] = $grantCode;
    $clienttoken_post["grant_type"] = "refresh_token";
}

$curl = curl_init($oauth2token_url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($grantCode);
print_r($json_response);
print_r(json_decode($json_response));
echo '</pre>';
```

**No refreshtoken here**

```
$authObj = json_decode($json_response);

//if offline access requested and granted, get refresh token
if (isset($authObj->refresh_token)) {
    global $refreshToken;
```

**no refresh token**
        $refreshToken = $authObj->refresh_token;
    }

```
$accessToken = $authObj->access_token;
return $accessToken;
```

}

**Modified code**

```
if ($grantType === "offline") {
    $clienttoken_post["grant_type"] = "authorization_code";
    $clienttoken_post["response_type"] = "code";

    $clienttoken_post["scope"] = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
    $clienttoken_post["redirect_uri"] = $redirect_uri;
}
```

**Also changed url from** https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think your code is correct. Please check the execution steps to verify that the correct code is executed.

Also try to update your SDK if its not the latest. When I had this problem, I updated the SDK and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

You need to request a token to use "offline" instead of "online" in order to get the refresh token back.

See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer for an overview of what is going on under the scenes, which will help understand the OAuth 2 Offline flow.

Comment: I changed it, but now it is showing error" :invalid_grant". Also is there any way to do this just by using the php sdk

Comment: Hi after reading the documentation I have updated the code. Now it is showing "Moved Temporarily". I solved this by adding curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); Now the problem is that the response is null . Please see the "Modified code" section above (at the end)

Comment: I tried to print the response returned. It is actually the login in page of google

Comment: I just now found out that if i specify client_secret in the request, it is telling  Error: invalid_request

Parameter not allowed for this message type: client_secret

Comment: And if remove client_secret then it shows Required parameter is missing: response_type. They documentation shows to give 5 parameters, and I have all 5 and nothing more

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-analytics-data-export-api/VQSjEL73bkY/hb3nauVND2QJ According to this forum the url should be /token rather than /auth. I tried both, but no use

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the PHP library. I posted the link to the OAuth2 flow documentation so you had some idea what was going on "under the scenes", what your PHP code needed to do, what it would be getting back, and why. Your original code seemed to be confusing "online" and "offline" flow.

As I noted elsewhere (either in your message to the Google Group or to your other question on this subject), I think another part of the problem is how you were handling the object that was returned and treating it as a string instead of as an object.

Comment: thank you for the response. I have updated the sdk and now its working properly

Answer (score -1):

Another possible cause for this message is to have incorrect CLIENT_ID or CLIENT_SECRET